# sqlalchemy query based on 2 other classes/tables with association table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the following tables (simplified version):

```
class MainTerm(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'main_term'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    text = db.Column(db.String)
```

Further I have gazetteers that I would like to use for filtering:

```
terms_in_gzt = db.Table('terms_in_gzt',
    db.Column('gzt_term_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('gzt_term.id')),
    db.Column('gazetteer_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('gazetteer.id')),
)

class Gazetteer(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'gazetteer'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    terms = db.relationship('GztTerm', secondary=terms_in_gzt, backref='gazetteers', lazy='dynamic')

class GztTerm(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'gzt_term'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    text = db.Column(db.String)
```

I would like to get a query that contains (or excludes) `MainTerm` entries that share the same `text` attribute with `GztTerm` given a certain `Gazetteer`.

So, when having `Gazetteer` with id `1`. I want to query all `MainTerm`s that share the same `text` attribute with one of the `GztTerm`s in `Gazetteer.query.get(1).terms`.

---

So far I have been able to limit `MainTerm` entries to *all* `GztTerm` entries, but not for a certain `Gazetteer`:

```
db.session.query(MainTerm)\
       .filter(MainTerm.text == GztTerm.text)
```

And Query all `GztTerm` entries of a certain `Gazetteer` instance:

```
db.session.query(GztTerm) \
       .join(terms_in_gzt) \
       .join(Gazetteer) \
       .filter((terms_in_gzt.c.gzt_term_id == GztTerm.id) & (terms_in_gzt.c.gazetteer_id == 1))
```

But I'm struggling bringing these together.

---

***In short: 
I want to query all `MainTerm` entries with `MainTerm.text == GztTerm.text` (or `!=`) for all `GztTerm` in `Gazetteer.query.get(1).terms`* (or any other given instance).**

Comment: did you consider the `in_` operator? if you have the following join
`joinq  = Query(GztTerm.text).join(terms_in_gzt).join(Gazetteer).filter(Gazetteer.id == 1)`

You can search for your entries with `res = session.query(MainTerm).filter(MainTerm.text.in_(joinq.subquery())).all()`

Comment: This is great! I found a solution, but this is much better suited for my purpose. Thanks! Do you want to add an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `in_` operator can be used here using the following join subquery:

```
joinq = Query(GztTerm.text).join(terms_in_gzt).join(Gazetteer).filter(Gazetteer.id == 1)
res = session.query(MainTerm).filter(MainTerm.text.in_(joinq.subquery())).all()
```